# PHPExcel: не получается реализовать строки

Tags: php, строки

Добрый день, есть вот такой вот массив, не как не получается из него слепить полноценный лист в PHPExcel по колонкам получается все норм а вот строки перезаписываются (

```
Array ( [Test1] => Array ( 
[data] => Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test1 [2] => test1 [3] => test1 => test1 [5] => test1 ) 
[date] => Array ( [0] => 16-08-2013 [1] => 22-08-2013 [2] => 22-08-2013 [3] => 22-08-2013 [4] => 22-08-2013 [5] => 23-08-2013 ) 
[stat] => Array ( [0] => 5854 [1] => 5854 [2] => 5854 [3] => 5854 [4] => 5854 [5] => 5854 ) )

Array ( [Test2] => Array ( 
    [data] => Array ( [0] => test1 [1] => test1 [2] => test1 [3] => test1 => test1 [5] => test1 ) 
    [date] => Array ( [0] => 16-08-2013 [1] => 22-08-2013 [2] => 22-08-2013 [3] => 22-08-2013 [4] => 22-08-2013 [5] => 23-08-2013 ) 
    [stat] => Array ( [0] => 5854 [1] => 5854 [2] => 5854 [3] => 5854 [4] => 5854 [5] => 5854 ) )

foreach($data as $key => $sers) {
        $col = 0;
        $row = 0;   
            foreach($sers as $keys => $serss) {
                $col++;
                    foreach($serss as $keysaa) {
                    $row = $row + 1;
                        $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col,$row,$keysaa);
                    }
            }
        $row++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
$row = 0; 
foreach($data as $key => $sers) {
    $col = 0;
```

У вас кстати странное задание массива, у меня оно ошибку дает

> [3] => test1 => test1

И собственно в нужных местах инкрементируйте row и col

Comment: спс, но нашел решения и пересоздал массив 

foreach($data as $key => $sers) { 
   foreach($sers as $keys => $serss) {
    if (!isset($datas[$keys]))
     $datas[$keys]= array(); 
    foreach($serss as $ke) { 
     $datas[$keys][] = $ke; 
    }
   }
 } 

 $col = 0;
 foreach($datas as $key => $sr) {
  $col++;
  $row = 0;
  foreach($sr as $srs) {
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col,$row,$srs);
    $row++;
  }
 
 }

Answer (score 0):

Пoсмотрите в сторону [fromArray()](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/77737)